# CMake: How to add a .obj 3d models to C++ Visual Studio UWP project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, uwp

I'm trying to add a 3d model to the resources of an Appx in a cmake build.  I have it successfully working with most formats, but files ending in .obj are being treated as compiled object files.

The cmake Visual Studio generator seems to always treat any file with an extension .obj as an object file and adds it to the vcxproj with the  tag.

Is there a way to change the internal type of a file that cmake is using?  Can I specify that this file is NOT an "EXTERNAL_OBJECT"?

Setting the VS_DEPLOYMENT_CONTENT to 1 doesn't help.
Adding it to the RESOURCES property doesn't help.

It looks like it might be an issue in the cmake source code itself where it checks if a file type if EXTERNAL_OBJECT before checking any other flags or types, and I can't figure out how to unset that type.

Answer (score 1):

As per this issue on the cmake gitlab repo https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18820, there is a hacky fix solution but no "correct" fix yet.

Brad King:

> As a very hacky not very futureproof workaround that abuses current implementation details, try:
>
> get_property(loc SOURCE myfile.obj PROPERTY LOCATION)
>
> set_property(SOURCE myfile.obj PROPERTY EXTERNAL_OBJECT 0)
>
> The first line forces [this code](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/v3.13.3/Source/cmSourceFile.cxx#L267-270) and therefore [this code](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/v3.13.3/Source/cmSourceFile.cxx#L212-216) to run, causing CMake to initialize the EXTERNAL_OBJECT property earlier than it normally would.  Once that is done then we can set the property back to 0.
>
> A possible fix would be to teach the latter code (in CheckExtension) to not set the EXTERNAL_OBJECT property if it is already set.  We can't change the default behavior of treating .obj files as objects to link, but we can at least make an explicit property setting work without the above hack.

I have confirmed that this works for the .obj files in our solution.